# Hidden Markov Model, Clarification on a Previous Implementation

Tags: java, hidden-markov-models

I'm experimenting with hidden markov models. I really have no prior experience working with them so I decided to check out a few examples of implementations.

Looking at the below implementation, I was a bit confused about the purpose of the Baum-Welch algorithm (found under the train method) taking a variable steps. I understand providing a training set, but not providing steps. Does anyone have an explanation for this, since I don't understand it from the documentation.

Here's a link to the original code http://cs.nyu.edu/courses/spring04/G22.2591-001/BW%20demo/HMM.java since the code isn't being presented very nicely in my post.

```
import java.text.*;

/** This class implements a Hidden Markov Model, as well as
the Baum-Welch Algorithm for training HMMs.
@author Holger Wunsch (wunsch@sfs.nphil.uni-tuebingen.de) 
*/
public class HMM {
  /** number of states */
  public int numStates;

  /** size of output vocabulary */
  public int sigmaSize;

  /** initial state probabilities */
  public double pi[];

  /** transition probabilities */
  public double a[][];

  /** emission probabilities */
  public double b[][];

  /** initializes an HMM.
  @param numStates number of states
  @param sigmaSize size of output vocabulary 
  */

 public HMM(int numStates, int sigmaSize) {
   this.numStates = numStates;
   this.sigmaSize = sigmaSize;

   pi = new double[numStates];
   a = new double[numStates][numStates];
   b = new double[numStates][sigmaSize];
 }

 /** implementation of the Baum-Welch Algorithm for HMMs.
  @param o the training set
  @param steps the number of steps
 */
  public void train(int[] o, int steps) {
     int T = o.length;
     double[][] fwd;
     double[][] bwd;

     double pi1[] = new double[numStates];
     double a1[][] = new double[numStates][numStates];
     double b1[][] = new double[numStates][sigmaSize];

     for (int s = 0; s < steps; s++) {
      /* calculation of Forward- und Backward Variables from the
 current model */
      fwd = forwardProc(o);
      bwd = backwardProc(o);

      /* re-estimation of initial state probabilities */
      for (int i = 0; i < numStates; i++)
    pi1[i] = gamma(i, 0, o, fwd, bwd);

      /* re-estimation of transition probabilities */ 
      for (int i = 0; i < numStates; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < numStates; j++) {
     double num = 0;
     double denom = 0;
     for (int t = 0; t <= T - 1; t++) {
       num += p(t, i, j, o, fwd, bwd);
       denom += gamma(i, t, o, fwd, bwd);
     }
   a1[i][j] = divide(num, denom);
  }
    }

  /* re-estimation of emission probabilities */
  for (int i = 0; i < numStates; i++) {
for (int k = 0; k < sigmaSize; k++) {
  double num = 0;
  double denom = 0;

  for (int t = 0; t <= T - 1; t++) {
    double g = gamma(i, t, o, fwd, bwd);
    num += g * (k == o[t] ? 1 : 0);
    denom += g;
  }
  b1[i][k] = divide(num, denom);
}
  }
  pi = pi1;
  a = a1;
  b = b1;
}
}


  /** calculation of Forward-Variables f(i,t) for state i at time
  t for output sequence O with the current HMM parameters
  @param o the output sequence O
  @return an array f(i,t) over states and times, containing
          the Forward-variables. 
  */

  public double[][] forwardProc(int[] o) {
int T = o.length;
double[][] fwd = new double[numStates][T];

/* initialization (time 0) */
for (int i = 0; i < numStates; i++)
  fwd[i][0] = pi[i] * b[i][o[0]];

/* induction */
for (int t = 0; t <= T-2; t++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < numStates; j++) {
fwd[j][t+1] = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < numStates; i++)
  fwd[j][t+1] += (fwd[i][t] * a[i][j]);
fwd[j][t+1] *= b[j][o[t+1]];
  }
}

return fwd;
}
```

The other two questions I have are in regards to the Forward method, which implements the Forward part of the Forward-Backward algorithm. From reading up on HMMs, I gather that, after training my model, I should use something like this method to predict future observations. So is the param O (representing output sequences) just the sequence of observations up until this point?

With some experimentation with this method, I'm returned what the documentation says are Forward-Variables, which just look like a bunch of probabilities. How are these translated into future observations?

I'm delving into regions of programming that are quite difficult for me, so I really appreciate your help in helping me understand this stuff!